# Cannot get data from Access database after making successful connection using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, combobox

I am writing C# code with a WPF project.  I have a ComboBox1 drop down where the user selects one item from a Microsoft Access Database on my computer. Right after the user selects something, I want to retrieve a certain value from the same row that the user just chose to go into a textblock.

I am getting 3 errors that are all the same and say "*The name 'connect' does not exist in the current context*."  I am not sure how to fix this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace bundlecalc
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainWindow_Load();
        }

        private void MainWindow_Load()
        {   
            OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
            connect.ConnectionString =  @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Projects\Database.accdb;
            Persist Security Info = False; ";
            connect.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1";

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader["Column1"].ToString());
            }
            connect.Close();

        }

        private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            connect.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            string query = "select * from Table1 where Column1 ='" + ComboBox1.Text + "'";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                BetaAnswer.Text = reader["ValueFromRow"].ToString();
            }

            connect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare connect  as class member

Comment: @viveknuna: Bad idea.  Keeping open connection objects around in a long-lived class is just asking for errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `MainWindow_Load` you declare the `connect` variable:

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
```

But in `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` you don't.  Simply declare it in that method as well.

You might also look into the `using` block for disposable resources like database connections.  Something like:

```
using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection())
{
    // use the connection
}
```

(You *might* be tempted to make the `connect` variable a class-level member that can be re-used by everything in the class.  Don't.  This is a famously bad idea.  The database connection should be created, used, and destroyed in a very small scope.  The connection pool takes care of re-use for you.  Trying to handle re-use yourself will lead to problems.)

Comment: Would like to add, that the OP shouldn't use ad hoc sql statements concatenated and user interface controls. Use parameterized queries or stored procedures.